# How to join 5 MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following 5 tables:

```
company
phone
website
city
state
```

Each table has 2 columns:

company - `id,company`

phone - `id,phone`

website - `id,website`

city - `id,city`

state - `id,state`

All that I'm trying to do is combine (join?) all 5 tables based on the `id` in each table.

Basically I want to output this:

```
id, company, phone, website, city, state
```

It looks like this should be done through a `JOIN` statement and I've seen several examples of this on StackOverflow, but every example looks wildly different to me.

Could someone point me in the right direction to get this done?

I only need to run the command one time, but it's on a table with about 2 million rows.

Comment: Do we assume that the Companies `id` column is used in all the other tables as the linking column (foreign key) i.e. each of the other tables `id` columns???

Comment: Lets see what you have tried! If you can JOIN 2 tables you can JOIN 100 tables, its just a case or repeating the idea (n) times

Comment: No, it is not set as the foreign key.  The `company` contains all `id`'s though.  Some of the other tables have missing ones - for example, not all companies have a phone number.

Comment: Yes ok. But if the companies `id=1` then (if data exists in the other tables) can we say that there will be a Phone with `id=1` and a website with `id=1` and a city and state with an `id=1`

Comment: And will those rows be therefore correctly linked?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't understand.  That is correct.  If `id=N` is in the `company` table, then it will match where `id=N` in any of the other tables.

Comment: You join 5 tables the same way you join 2, 3, or 4 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it is a simple

```
SELECT c.id, company, phone, website, city, state
FROM Company c
    LEFT JOIN phone p ON p.id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN website w ON w.id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN city ci ON ci.id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN state s ON s.id=c.id
ORDER BY company
```